# Navigation based iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

How would I go about creating a navigation based application that for each item in the list goes to a different website. 
Eg:
Item 1 --->google.
Item 2 --->stackoverflow.
Item 3 --->facebook.

I am tried many things but cannot seem to get it working. I've looked at UICatalog but cannot think of how to implement what i need.
A quick walkthrough would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can take an array in that enter url list of arrays as follows:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@"Google",@"Stackoverflow",@"facebook",nil];
```

Then display these items first in tableviewcell.

After that add viewcontrollers, in that you can write the code what you want to show in that view using `UIWebview`.

```
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
NSString *str = @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:req];
[self.view addSubView:web];
```

Comment: @ Krishnan G... hope you understand the other basics, like creating tableViews and ViewControllers, in that case following Chakradhar's comment will be easy task for you.

Comment: ive created the table view but how do i create the ViewControllers, sorry im really new to this.

Comment: i mean, ive created the viewcontroller but how do i link to them, thanks

Comment: Did u get the items in tableview?    If u got that, then right click on classes under group &Files, Click on Add Newfile and add UIViewcontroller subclass. then write ur webview code in that .m file ok.....

Comment: @Chakradhar Ive added the webview code to the new .m file but how do i get to that view from the navigationcontroller?

I've thought of this..

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
 NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;  
}

Also, my situation is exactly like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353501/uiviewcontrollers-and-uiwebview

Put it just confuses me.
I appreciate all your help.

Thanks

Comment: @Krishan G.. The code which is written for webview should place in the new class .m file in viewDidLoad method. First u display all the tableview items. Then add one class for eg: First . Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method write the code as                   follows...            First *a = [[First alloc]initWithNibName:@'First" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationControlleer pushViewController:a animated:YES]; [a release];  Then in First.m file , at viewDidLoad method , u can write webview code.  ok